# Tridion Outbound emails - Mailing statistics - Can we hide some columns like failed/Delivered

Tags: outbound-email

Please help me,, Can we hide some columns like Failed/delivered from the mailing statistics. Please refer the below screenshot as shown I want to hide the Delivered and Failed status from the statistics[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no configuration setting for that, but it's possible to do in a UI extension. You would basically write a Data Extender which modifies the output for the response to the list header XML - removing the columns you don't want.

Be sure this is what all of your users want, though. Most people are quite interested in how many e-mails were delivered but not read, or failed to be delivered in the first place (although it seems like you haven't set that up, since they're all 0).

Comment: Thanks a lot peter.. Yes we are not having any bounce server configured here so I could track the failed email. I will try to implement the above give by you. Thanks